# MySQL move rows from one table to another by condition

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL database of users, their sold and purchased products. We need to move inactive users who have not logged-in from last 3 years and never purchased or sold anything on our website to another table. Each table has millions of entries.

This is a table for sold items. Around 40m entries;

```
CREATE TABLE `sold` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is a table for purchased items. Around 6m entries;

```
CREATE TABLE `purchased` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is a user table, around 17m entries;

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_index` (`email`),
  KEY `lastlogin` (`lastlogin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the table where we need to move inactive users to

```
CREATE TABLE `inactiveusers` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_index` (`email`),
  KEY `lastlogin` (`lastlogin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this with minimum downtime?

Answer (score 0):

@Yumoji, I guess your probelm is How to calculate the last three 3 years of any activity. Right?

So, if that is the case then you should add a "created_at" column in your DB tables.

Now, after you add a created_at column in your tables you can easily calculate last three years activity.
Here it is-

```
SELECT uid FROM sold AND purchased WHERE sold.created_at>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) OR purchased.created_at>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
```

from this query you get the user ids, Then -

```
INSERT INTO inactiveusers select * from users where uid = 'the user ids u get';
DELETE FROM users where uid = 'the user ids u get';
```

I hope it solves problem. Cheers.